# OpenFileDialog - Check if has not been selected

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a procedure to Open a file from Excel. I want to insert a check, if the user presses Open without selecting a file, then have a message box pop warning.

Here is a portion of my code where I want to insert the check. I tried using `Is Nothing`, but it did not work for me.

```
            If GetOpenFileName.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                fileStream = GetOpenFileName.OpenFile()

                If (fileStream Is Nothing) Then 'I tried checking here, but it does not fire.
                    vmbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No Workbook Seletected")

                    If vmbContinue = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
                        xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                        Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know what exactly you are asking for, but this is the code I use when opening files, and if they dont select one, it wont let them.

```
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    With ofd
        'select the atributes before opening
        'the filename (will show in the filename box)
        .FileName = ""
        'the title of the window to open a file
        .Title = "Open File..."
        'the extension filter
        .Filter = "Exel Files|*.exel"
        ''now to open the dialogue and check if OK has been pressed
        If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox("File Opened Sucessfully")
            'put the code here when they choose a file
        Else
            MsgBox("Please Select A File")
            'put the code here if they click cancel or close
        End If
    End With
```